# Put two windows into one

Tags: windows, taskbar, window

I am running Windows 7. I have two windows that I want to view at the same time on the same screen with each window having its own icon in the taskbar, for example Word on the left and Excel on the right. I want to put both windows into one window so that only one icon appears in the taskbar. When I click this icon both programs will appear together in one overall window.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is possible using the Taskview feature "New Desktop" on Windows 10. Similar to how the 'workspace' or 'session' concept might work. For Win7, you might try using an app that lets you change desktop workspaces. If I remember correctly, the old ATi Radeon Catalyst driver package came with such an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put multiple applications into one taskbar icon. But you can change when the taskbar groups the icons. AS for two windows on the same screen just drag the window to the edge of the screen and drag the other window to the opposite side. If you have dual monitors just hit windows key and either the left or right arrow key. This will snap the applications to the side of the monitor instead of the edge of the desktop.

To change the taskbar grouping behavior:
Right click the `taskbar` > click `properties`. From the `taskbar tab` under `taskbar appearance` go to the `taskbar buttons` drop down and select one of the following options:

- Never combine -- Will do exactly that Never combine the taskbar Icons and all windows will have there own button on the taskbar.
- Combine -- When taskbar is full will keep the Icons on the desktop separate until more room on the taskbar is needed. It will then group the Icons based off of applications.
- Always combine, hide labels -- When this option is selected the taskbar will always group the Icons on the taskbar by application.

  The Best you can do is to group the icons all the time. This will never combine multiple applications in one taskbar button.

If you really want to go overboard you could start up a virtual machine and have the two applications started up on that and sitting there waiting ready and just switch to the VM when you want to pull up both applications.

look at the accepted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/359191/how-can-i-make-multiple-programs-occupy-one-icon-space-in-the-windows-task-bar), the links provided may work.

Comment: I would like two separate windows to share one taskbar icon so that I click on one button and two windows open.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to another [question](http://superuser.com/questions/359191/how-can-i-make-multiple-programs-occupy-one-icon-space-in-the-windows-task-bar) which may have a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

**To view two windows on your desktop side by side** you can use the [Snap](http://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip101.htm) feature of Windows 7 and work on them without overlapping or minimizing the other one.

**For each windows to have it's separate taskbar icon** you can choose `never combine` option of 'taskbar button' property from taskbar properties, by right clicking on the taskbar.

With `always combine` option you can **overlap** the icon of the windows of the same program but there's no way to convert either taskbar icons or windows of two separate programs into one.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a Autohotkey-Script to open and resize the two windows and pin it to the bar...

To activate/open the windows
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

Then resize the window as you need it:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm

Obviously, you will still have two windows, but as far as I understand your question, this is the problem you want to solve.

Much simpler than a VM imho ;-)

Comment: You really should provide examples of how to use those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Install Stardock Groupy to merge two windows in one with tabs. Or learn how to use virtual desktops, on Windows 10 those are built-in.

Comment: Nice find. I’d say this answer could benefit from a screenshot!

Comment: Explaining how one does this will make it an answer. Right now it is just a comment noting something is possible.